Twilio Record Verb Initial Time out
I have a requirement to record the user prompt during the phone conversation.
I am using Twilio SDK. Below is the sample code.
var response = new VoiceResponse();
response.Say("Please state you name");
response.Record(timeout: 2, 
                action: new Uri("call back url"), 
                method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
                playBeep: true);

Per the code, below is what happens

User picks up the phone
User hears the prompt: Please state you name
Recording starts for the user to state the name
User says the name
after 2 seconds of pause (timeout: 2), the recording with stop.

This works fine when the user immediately says the name as soon as the prompt "Please state you name" is over. But if the user takes any more than 2 seconds to start talking, the recording is stopped automatically since the time out is set to 2 seconds.
One way to solve the issue is to increase the timeout (may be set it to 5 seconds). But I have a limitation on the timeout after the prompt, I can not wait any more than 2 seconds after the user is done talking.
How can I deal with this requirement? Ideas are welcome.
Is there any attribute in Record verb like starttimeout or something, which will track the number of seconds it can wait before the user starts talking and then endtimeout which is similar to current timeout attribute which will track the number of seconds after the prompt.
